# Kernel upgrade from patch

Tags: linux-kernel, upgrade, patch

If I would like to upgrade my kernel from 3.10.80 to 3.16.1 by kernel source patching, what is the best way to do it? I hope I would not need to patch each version one by one..

Comment: Have you cloned it from mainline kernel? `git tag` may help in this case.

Comment: Hello SD, I can successfully download each incremented patch and apply it. For example, from 3.10.80 to 3.10.81. But I am wondering if I should do this up to 3.16.1?

Comment: I would go the other route. Diff my custom kernel against mainline, to create my own patch file, i.e. ` diff -pruN linux-3.10.80 my_kernel >my_patch`.  Then apply that patch to the new kernel version.  Be prepared for touch-ups.

Comment: I see what you mean, thanks! will give it a try then!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mainline kernel tree (i.e. origin is set to *git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git)* then you can do the following.

If not, then first clone the kernel with,

> $ git clone
>   git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git

Now you can switch to desired kernel version by means of *tag*, and if you require the patches between the two versions, go ahead.

Diff the changes between v3.10.80 and v3.16.1 with below method

> $ git checkout -b v3.16.1 v3.16.1
>
> $ git checkout -b v3.10.80 v3.10.80

```
$ git branch
  master
* v3.10.80
  v3.16.1
```

Now you are on v3.10.80, the following command will create patch of each commit between both the versions.

```
$ git format-patch v3.16.1
```

If you want to make a single patch,

```
$ git diff v3.10.80 v3.16.1 -- > v3.10.80_to_v3.16.1.diff
```

Comment: What the... ?! The topic started obviously didn't get Git (yet).